# Xcode 12.4 "You don't have permission to save the file..." running on CATALINA

Tags: xcode, locked

I apologize if this question has already been answered but I can't find an answer anywhere. I recently updated to Catalina and Xcode 12.4. The issue is that now suddenly I can't save to my existing project. It will open, however when I try and save any .swift file, I am getting the error message "The document “ViewController.swift” could not be saved. The file is locked.".

However, this is incorrect, the file isn't locked and I have given Xcode and Terminal full disk access in the preferences.

Anybody know what I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried copy the project to a new directory and open it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems a few times. I am using OneDrive sync and today I had just set the sync on pause (as I also had the last time it occured) to get rid of the fan noise (why is the fan running every time OneDrive is working?) when the file problems occured. So I restarted OneDrive and let it sync again, and now all good